# Speaker doesn't mute when head phone is plugged

Tags: 12.04, headphones, mute

Ubuntu 12.04 
HP dv7-3170 with Codec: IDT 92HD75B3X5

i solved this problem by adding the following line to alsa-base.conf

options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5 enable_msi=1

yesterday after applying all updates via update manager i have no sound on my speakers and on my earphones.
if i comment the above line in alsa-base.conf i get sound again and also get my original problem.

what can i do to revert changes...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround to this problem.

I found that the problem is with the kernel version.

Previously, I had version `3.2.0.24` and after upgrade I got `3.2.0.25`.

As a workaround, I have to select the previous kernel version in the `grub` boot menu.